# using macro in method definition and implementation

Tags: objective-c, ios

i would like to know what are the best practices witch you are using when developing for many targets in one project in iOS. I have something like this in the .h :

(target1 and targetX are preprocessor macro)

```
#if target1
-(void)logOut:(UIButton*)sender;
#endif
```

and sometimes i am using something like this ( in the .m) :

```
#if targetX
-(void)logOut:(UIButton*)sender{
.....
}
#endif
```

am i doing it the right way ? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer to your question is yes, as long as one target defines `-Dtarget1=1` and the other target defines `-DtargetX=1`, then you are doing this correctly.

If you have added an additional compiler flag to one target such as:

```
-Dtarget1=1
```

Then code inside:

```
#if target1
    // code specific to target1
#endif
```

will be part of the compiled app.

If you were to have the flag:

```
-Dtarget1=0
```

then anything inside:

```
#if target1
    // code specific to target1
#endif
```

will NOT be part of the compiled app.

When using multiple targets you can do things like:

```
#if target1
    // code specific to target1
#elif targetX
    // code specific to targetX
#endif
```